# How to avoid of cycling Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is html template.

```
<div id="block" style="display:none;">
    <button id="close">Close</button>
</div>
<button id="call_func">Run</button>
```

Here is js

```
    var $block = $('#block'),
        $runBtn = $('#call_func');

    var func = function($el){

        var $makeLogBtn = $el.find('#close');

        $makeLogBtn.on('click', function(){
            console.log('Yo');
            $el.hide();
        });

        $el.show();

    }

    $runBtn.on('click', function(){
        new func($block);
    });
```

When I click on close btn first time I received one console.log string. On running function again and push 'close' btn, I've got console message already 3 times. Next pushing gives me 6 console strings total instead of 3. I understand, that first function continue working also. How to prevent it?

**The only thing I need is to distruct all the function every time after it's 'close' method calling**

https://jsfiddle.net/sxsnbcsr/

Comment: as per your thinking.. how many times, it should give message?, @Sergey Kudryashov

Comment: because each time you click on `Run` a new click handler is added

Comment: One clickinh on 'close' = one message.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.off()` to remove all event handlers before binding a new one

```
$makeLogBtn.off().on('click', function(){
    console.log('Yo');
    $el.hide();
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxsnbcsr/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use .one()

```
    $makeLogBtn.one('click', function () {
        console.log('Yo');
        $el.hide();
    });
```

Demo: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vc3v5331/)

Comment: Yes, I know about "one", but I'm looking for better solution, coz sometimes I need click on the button several times before the block is closed.

Comment: @SergeyKudryashov then use .off() with a namespaced event name

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
    var $block = $('#block'),
        $runBtn = $('#call_func'),
        $makeLogBtn = $el.find('#close');

    var func = function($el){
        $el.show();
    }
    $makeLogBtn.on('click', function(){
       console.log('Yo');
       $block.hide();
    });
    $runBtn.on('click', function(){
        func($block);
    });
```

#### [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxsnbcsr/2/)

Comment: Yes, it's good. But I want to keep all code in one function like an object from the class. ANd to delete this object after closing